# "IF loop not working in EXCEL Macros"

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  TextBox2.Value = 10
  TextBox3.Value = 5
  TextBox2.Value = (CInt(TextBox2))
  TextBox3.Value = (CInt(TextBox3))

  If TextBox2.Value > TextBox3.Value Then
    ActiveSheet.Select
    UserForm5.Show
  End If
End Sub
```

The control is not going in the IF loop, and "USerForm5 is not getting displayed.

Can anyone pls help.

Reagrds

Comment: What is `TextBox2.Value = (CInt(TextBox2))` is used for?

Comment: FYI, IF is not a loop, it's a control structure.

Comment: Most likely that `TextBox.Value` property cannot hold an integer and converts it back to string. Nice little gotcha.

Comment: It is common in StackOverflow to Accept answers that work by selecting the large tick. An up vote is always good, too. Answers that help, but do not solve the problem can also be up-voted. You will find notes in the FAQ in the top bar.

Answer (score 4):

The comparison is being done as strings. Wrap the `CInt()` calls around the values in the `IF` statement and you'll be good.

```
TextBox2.Value = 10
TextBox3.Value = 5
If CInt(TextBox2.Value) > CInt(TextBox3.Value) Then
```